# Kotest test factory and beforeSpec

Tags: kotlin, kotest

**Update** While searching for the optimal solution, I switched temporarily to an approach using a dedicated test factory that performs the init in combination with `forAll`. In this way, I don't have to repeat the init code in every test factory.

```
fun somePreStuffFactory() = funSpec {
    beforeTest {
        println("Do some init stuff here")
    }

    test("dummy test just to trigger beforeTest") {}
}

class MyTest : FunSpec({
    runBlocking {
        forAll(
            row(MyTestFactory::someTest1),
            row(MyTestFactory::someTest2)
        ) { testFactoryFunc ->
            include(somePreStuffFactory())
            include(testFactoryFunc())
        }
    }
})
```

*End of update*

I have a lot of tests inside test factories. Before running the tests inside a test factory, I need to do some initial setup in the beginning of each test factory, and the setup is the same for all test factories.

Problem is that `beforeSpec` is not invoked inside test factory, hence I'm currently using a dirty workaround by doing init stuff in the first test in each test factory. I would highly appreciate any advice on this.

The optimal solution would be to have a life-cycle hook inside the the test class that runs before each test factory.

**Code to reproduce**

```
class MyTest : FunSpec({
    include(someTest1())
    include(someTest2())
})
```

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.funSpec

object MyTestFactory {
    fun someTest1() = funSpec {
        beforeSpec {
            /** Not invoked */
            println("Hello from someTest1#beforeSpec")
        }

        test("Init stuff is done inside a test") {
            /** some init here */
        }

        test("first test") {
            println("Hello from first test")
        }

        test("second test") {
            println("Hello from second test")
        }
    }

    fun someTest2() = funSpec {
        beforeSpec {
            /** Not invoked */
            println("Hello from someTest2#beforeSpec")
        }

        test("Init stuff is done inside a test") {
            /** some init here */
        }

        test("third test") {
            println("Hello from third test")
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried so far**

After bumping Kotest from 4.6.4 to 5.4.2, I was able to run the code in answer from @ocos. Problem is that BeforeSpecSample#beforeSpec is invoked just once, not for each test factory which is my requirement.

```
object BeforeSpecSample : BeforeSpecListener {
    override suspend fun beforeSpec(spec: Spec) {
        println("Hello from beforeSpec")
    }
}

class MyTest : FunSpec({
    extensions(BeforeSpecSample)

    include(someTest1())
    include(someTest2())
})
```

**Update**
After reading [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues/458), I successfully tested the following approach using a boolean var `initialized` and`beforeTest`. It would have been nice if this approach could be used inside test class instead of inside each test factory, but without any life-cycle hooks for test factories, I don't see how that can be done.

```
fun someTest1() = funSpec {
    var initialized = false

    beforeTest {
        if (!initialized) {
            println("Hello from someTest1#beforeTest")
            initialized = true
        }
    }

    /** tests goes here */
}
```

**Environment**
Kotest 4.6.4, Kotlin 1.7.10, Micronaut 3.6.3

[Kotest test factory doc](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/test-factories.html)

Comment: Maybe you can go for the before container/after container listeners? They might help https://kotest.io/docs/framework/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: @LeoColman: Thanks for the suggestion. I just completed testing `beforeContainer` in both test class and in test factory. Neither of them was invoked. The reason for this, I believe, is that there are no tests in test class, only includes. In test factory, `beforeContainer` suffers from the same issue as `beforeSpec`. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind grouping everything inside a test factory in a `context` block, you could use a `BeforeContainerListener` for initialization:

```kotlin
object InitExtension : BeforeContainerListener {
    override suspend fun beforeContainer(testCase: TestCase) {
        if(testCase.parent == null) {
            println("init stuff")
        }
    }
}
```

The `if(testCase.parent == null)` is just there to allow your factory to have other nested `context`s that will not trigger an additional invocation of the initialization.

Then you can write your factory like this:

```kotlin
fun someTest1() = funSpec {
    extension(InitExtension)
    context("someTest1") {
        test("first test") {
            println("Hello from first test")
        }

        test("second test") {
            println("Hello from second test")
        }
    }
}
```

The initialization in `InitExtension` will be called at the beginning of `context` `someTest1`, and can analogously be included in other test factories that can each be initialized by the same extension.

Comment: This works as expected, thanks a lot. For others, it is worth mentioning that `InitExtension` may also be defined as a class with constructor params in case e.g. services are required (as in my case). BR

Answer (score 0):

`include` is using only tests and extensions defined in your `someTest()`'s TestFactory. This is why `beforeSpec` not invoked.

You can register an `extension` in your `MyTest`. Here is an example.

```kotlin
// you may use object MyTestFactory : BeforeSpecListener 

object BeforeSpecSample : io.kotest.core.listeners.BeforeSpecListener {

  override suspend fun beforeSpec(spec: Spec) {
    println("-> before spec <-")
  }
}

class MyTest : FunSpec({
  extensions(BeforeSpecSample)

  include(someTest())

  test("my test 1") { println("my test 1") }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After bumping Kotest from 4.6.4 to 5.1.0 (newer versions gives NoClassDefFound kotlinx/coroutines/CopyableThreadContextElement), I was able to run your code. Problem is that BeforeSpecSample#beforeSpec is invoked just once, not for each test factory which is my requirement. BR